# Is this the correct way to insert a relationship in linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I'm new to linq and I'm trying to write an update statement.

I have two tables, tblProject and tblPage. the two are linked via a foreign key in tblPage.

So when trying to create a row in tblPage this it th inq query I have

```
    public void CreatePage(int projectId, string pageName, DateTime createdDate, int createdBy, DateTime updatedDate, int updatedBy)
    {
        using (EverythingEngineEntities db = new EverythingEngineEntities())
        {
            Page page = new Page();
            page.Project = db.ProjectSet.Single(p => p.ProjectId == projectId);
            page.LastUpdatedBy = updatedBy;
            page.LastUpdatedDate = updatedDate;
            page.CreatedBy = createdBy;
            page.CreatedDate = createdDate;
            page.PageName = pageName;
        }
    }
```

What I want to know is this the correct way of inserting a row via linq to Entities.

Sorry if none of this makes sense :)

Edit:

I'm particulary interested if this line is the correct way

```
page.Project = db.ProjectSet.Single(p => p.ProjectId == projectId);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost done... you have to actually insert it though... (you've created it, which is step 1).

The code is something like:

```
db.Pages.InsertOnSubmit(page);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

I realize that's LINQ to SQL syntax there... but EF is pretty close.

EDIT: I was close... for EF it's

```
db.Pages.Add(page);
```

EDIT2: By the way, I forgot to mention that you don't **have** to hit the server if you're doing something as simple as above. I'm pretty sure you can do something like this in EF:

```
page.Project.ProjectID = projectID;
```

So you don't have to download the "db.ProjectSet.Single" just to re-insert it.

Comment: Sorry, thats just me being slack and not adding it the code :S

Answer (score 0):

I think your way is correct but your way will create an extra call.

You can replace

```
page.Project = db.ProjectSet.Single(p => p.ProjectId == projectId);
```

with

```
   page.ProjectReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("EverythingEngineEntities.Project", "ProjectID", projectId);
```

[Read this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/05/15/setting-an-entityreference-using-an-entitykey-in-entity-framework.aspx)